# Benchmarking CPU and File IO for an application running on Linux

Tags: linux, benchmarking

I wrote two programs to run on Linux, each using a different algorithm, and I want to find a way (preferably using a benchmarking software) to compare the CPU usage and IO operations between these two programs.

Is there such a thing? and if yes, where can I find them. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `/usr/bin/time -v`

Comment: I just tried it and it displays user time is seconds, and I'm getting 0 for the most part. I'm running small programs. anything that will give me more precision?

Comment: Since the hardware has limited time precision (and also because the kernel is scheduling processes, caching file systems, etc....) you need to change your program or their invocation to make them run for a few seconds, and repeat the benchmarking a few times

Answer (score 0):

You can try [hardinfo](http://www.howtogeek.com/111617/how-to-benchmark-your-linux-system-3-open-source-benchmarking-tools/)

Or there are like n different [tools](http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/) measuring system performance if measuring it while running your app solves your purpose

And you can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649678/command-line-benchmark-tool)

Answer (score 0):

You might try vmstat command:

```
vmstat 2 20 > vmstat.txt
20 samples of 2 seconds

bi = KB in, bo = KB out with wa = waiting for I/O
I/O can also increase cache demands
%CPU utilisation = us (user) = sy (system)

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io----  -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo    in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 277504  17060  82732    0    0    91    87  1432  236 11  3 84  1
 0  0      0 277372  17068  82732    0    0     0    24  1361  399 23  8 59 10
test start
 0  1      0 275240  17068  82732    0    0     0   512  1342  305 24  4 69  4
 2  1      0 275232  17068  82780    0    0    24 10752  4176  216  7  8  0 85
 1  1      0 275240  17076  82732    0    0 12288  2590  5295  243 15  8  0 77
 0  1      0 275240  17076  82748    0    0     8 11264  4329  214  6 12  0 82
 0  1      0 275240  17076  82780    0    0    16 11264  4278  233 15 10  0 75
 0  1      0 275240  17084  82780    0    0 19456   542  6563  255 10  7  0 83
 0  1      0 275108  17084  82748    0    0  5128  3072  3501  265 16 37  0 47
 3  1      0 275108  17084  82748    0    0   924  5120  8369 3845 12 33  0 55
 0  1      0 275116  17092  82748    0    0  1576    85 11483 6645  5 50  0 45
 1  1      0 275116  17092  82748    0    0     0   136  2304  689  3  9  0 88
 2  1      0 275084  17100  82732    0    0     0   352  2374  800 14 26  0 61
 0  0      0 275076  17100  82732    0    0   546   118  2408 1014 35 17 47  1
 0  1      0 275076  17104  82732    0    0     0    62  1324   76  3  2 89  7
 1  1      0 275076  17108  82732    0    0     0   452  1879  442  8 13 66 12
 0  0      0 275116  17108  82732    0    0   800   352  2456 1195 19 17 56  8
 0  1      0 275116  17112  82732    0    0     0    54  1325   76  4  1 88  8
test end
 1  1      0 275116  17116  82732    0    0     0   510  1717  286  6 10 72 11
 1  0      0 275076  17116  82732    0    0  1600  1152  3087 1344 23 29 41  7
```